# Magento different detail page for different product types

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I have a problem, I want to display different detail pages for different types of products. Actually I've installed **Unirgy Gift Certification** plug in and I want a different kind of page to be loaded for this type of product.

I added following code in **catalog.xml**, but it does not seems to be working

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_ugiftcert translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Gift Certificate)</label>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view-gift.phtml" />
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_ugiftcert" name="product.info.ugiftcert" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.ugiftcert.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_ugiftcert>
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? 
Is it possible to have different detail pages for different types of product? like different one for configurable/simple product or different detail page based on attribute set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update like that if that layout is being called.
I wrote a very quick post here a while ago. http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2010/12/17/magento-layout-handels-and-layout-xml-files/

What you need to do is go into the product controller and in the view action put the following code after the loadLayout() call.

```
$this->loadLayout();
print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());die();
//     .... OTher COde
```

This will display all the handles avaliable. If you do not see you handle in here then it will not be loaded.

```
PRODUCT_TYPE_ugiftcert
```

Comment: acually I used this : `print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());` to get the layout loaded, but, what I want here is : I wanted to load an entirely different **view.phtml** in case of `PRODUCT_TYPE_ugiftcert`, is it possible to do some hack in **catalog.xml** and tell it to load entirely  different **view-gift.phtml**

Comment: Yes, if you handle is is the list then your code should work, and change the template to catalog/product/view-gift.phtml

You could also use an observer and when the block is loaded for the product page check the loaded product and if is of the ugiftcert type then change the template for the block.